# Where has this bounty come from?

Tags: support, status-completed

I'm just curious. This [question](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/1488/what-is-the-avatamsaka-sutra-about) has got a generous bounty from Community. I've never seen this before. How does the Community user grant bounties? I thought only 'real' users could do this. What's the story here?. It's also sending us nice messages.

> Before I leave, I give this bounty to you. May it bring you peace and
>   happiness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was bountied by a real user who subsequently deleted their account. Note that this means the bounty can only be automatically awarded: when it expires, if any answer is above +2, the highest-voted answer will receive the bounty.

Comment: That was generous of that person. Thank you to them